# Android Studio 3 appcompat resourses not found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Hey I have a problem with Android Studio 3(Beta-2)

Every time I create new/open existing project it shows me following errors:

[image: Error]

Clean, Rebuild, Restart Studio, Removing gradle files don't work.

In the studio 2.3, everything is fine.

My `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    dataBinding.enabled = true
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.valentun.findgift"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
         exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.7.0'

    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'


    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.6.0@aar'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project's graddle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://jitpack.io'
    }
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: can you show gradle.build file

Comment: @NguyễnTrungHiếu, yes, I've added it.

Comment: `allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}` did you added this in your root build.gradle file

Comment: Do once clean project and the rebuild project from the build option in task bar  and also delete the .gradle file  from the project folder

Comment: I think, there's something wrong with the path... screensho says "c:\Users\????\.gradle\<rest_of_the_path>". Can you try to shift your project to root (c:\) & then clean & build the project again

Comment: Try, File -> Invalidate Cache

Comment: Or as @AshishJohn, your path maybe containing non-ascii character https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171968/your-project-path-contains-non-ascii-characters-android-studio

Comment: @ValiaSergeev check my answer below

Comment: @AshishJohn but in studio 2.3 it works fine, may be it is a bug in 3rd version?

Comment: @ValiaSergeev may be, but sometimes, long paths are not acceptable & give random errors

Answer (score 0):

Remove Gradle files (.gradle folder) from your project folder (C:\Users.....gradle) and try reopening the Android Studio.

Hope this will help.

Comment: @ValiaSergeev Did you clean and rebuild after the delete?

Comment: Yes, i did it. Folder creates again and studio shows the same error

Answer (score 0):

Change version 25 to 26

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "seesaa.vn.testandroidstudio"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0'
}
```

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0' to 26.0.1

Comment: You use android studio 3.0 beta. It only support version above 26. current version 26.0.1

Comment: I've updated the compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion and libraries to 26th version - still the same error

Comment: Have you changed the version to 26.0.1 of cardview and design yet?

Answer (score 0):

Your compile SDK version must match the support library's major version.

Since you are using version 25 of the support library, you need to compile against version 25 of the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Try **File -> invalidate caches / Restart**. Hope this will help.