# Android Studio setup wizard doesnt show symbolic links

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, symlink

While installing Android Studio 3.0.1 for Win 10 64-bit, my path to SDK contained non-ASCII characters.
So I created a symbolic link like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171968/your-project-path-contains-non-ascii-characters-android-studio/33938096). I ran cmd as admin.

But when I try to select the link in the setup wizard, to solve the ASCII problem, the link doesn't show up, only normal and hidden folders show up. I don't see the symbolic link i created.

I have selected random folder, but couldn't install anything. I went on, the "Welcome to Android Studio" window popped up. I selected Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure. I tried to type the location of the symbolic link in "Android SDK location", but it said, "The path does not belong to the directory"...

What to do to show up the symbolic link?

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already solved your problem, but I came across your question the other day trying to solve the same issue, so I will answer in case anyone else ends up here with the same question.

**If the symbolic link does not lead to an already existing folder, it won't show up in the Android Studio setup wizard.**

You are creating a symbolic link to the Local/Android/Sdk folder, so make sure that folder actually exists. Just try to click on your symbolic link at C:/android-sdk and see if it takes you anywhere, if it gives an error instead, Local/Android/Sdk does not yet exist and that is probably the reason why your symbolic link does not show up in Android Studio. You might try to create Local/Android/Sdk by yourself before creating the symbolic link, but I can't vouch for that solution.