# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. (Flutter) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'

Tags: flutter

I am getting this error when trying to run Flutter on virtual android device. What is the reason? I even reinstalled android studio from scratch. I also did the SDK installs.

[image: problem]

I am getting this error message. What is the reason?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171968/your-project-path-contains-non-ascii-characters-android-studio

Comment: please post your error as a text.

Comment: The console output should be shared in text rather than graphics, in between 3 apostrophes, like so:
```
code, log, console output etc.
```