# Flutter Your project path contains non-ASCII characters

Tags: flutter

I encounter this problem, I tried a lot of different solutions, the solutions I tried are just below the output of the cmd.

````
aunching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
main.dart:1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\emott\OneDrive\Masa�st�\myapp\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
Your project path contains non-ASCII characters. This will most likely cause the build to fail on Windows. Please move your project to a different directory. See http://b.android.com/95744 for details. This warning can be disabled by adding the line 'android.overridePathCheck=true' to gradle.properties file in the project directory.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org/

BU�LD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)```


**I tried these:
1- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49507
2- https://www.flutterforum.org/d/303-gradle-hatasi-kafayi-yedirdi
3- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171968/your-project-path-contains-non-ascii-characters-android-studio**
````

Comment: Try moving your project to a directory named with ASCII characters as it is asking.

Answer (score 0):

Well my desktop name was Turkish (Masaüstü) that was the reason I open the project in C disc and problem is solved..